# In the function below, IE says that ')' is missing:

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

same code working in chrome and edge, but not working in ie

```
function PostAVWorkspaceTab(ParamURL, title = "") {

      var DecodedURL = decodeURL(ParamURL); 
      const queryStringTitleValue = getQueryStringValueByKey(DecodedURL, 'Title');

      var jsonData = {};
      jsonData["MessageId"] = 1;
      jsonData["Title"] = queryStringTitleValue ? queryStringTitleValue : title;
      jsonData["URL"] = DecodedURL;
      jsonData["ObjectId"] = 0;

      try {
         window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(jsonData), "http://localhost:9002/TokenInfo");
      }
      catch (e) { }

      console.log("PostAVWorkspaceTab(4): send message to open tab with URL = [" + DecodedURL + "] - " + "http://localhost:9002/TokenInfo" + jsonData);


}
```

Comment: I think the Problem is the default param value

Comment: [IE doesn't support default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility), `PostAVWorkspaceTab(ParamURL, title = "") {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in line  PostAVWorkspaceTab(ParamURL, title = "") - to be specific the second parameter - title.

IE doesn't support default value in the parameter. Try this:

```
PostAVWorkspaceTab(ParamURL, title) {
  if (title === undefined){
    title = "";
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: You can write this shorter:
`title = title || ''`

Answer (score 0):

As already informed by other community members, the IE browser do not support default parameters.

[image]

Reference:

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility)

This is the reason that you are getting an error in the IE browser.

To fix the issue you can try to remove the default value for the parameter and only try to pass the parameter will fix the issue.

You can try to implement any other logic like passing the empty value and check if the value is empty then try to use default value from the variable in function.